# How to Capture outgoing http/https request through rhel7 linux server?

Tags: http, unix, networking, python-requests, rhel7

I am execute python script that do http/https request. And I want to capture all the outgoing request will be done via python script.

So Is there any way to track all the outgoing request on server level.

Comment: You can use tcpdump, in bash: https://sites.google.com/site/jimmyxu101/testing/use-tcpdump-to-monitor-http-traffic

Comment: Through tcpdump i can only able to track http request , not able to see any log related https request. And tcpdump command only able to run through root user , if i want to track all the http/https request through my individual unix id then is there any other unix package or any other way in rhel7 server

Comment: maybe you can update your python script to log the http/s requests to a log file (like /var/log/nginx/access.log, /var/log/apache2/access.log, etc), then you can process this information.

Comment: You could setup an Apache web server on your localhost.  This Apache would act as a proxy to the actual site you want to access.  Or look tools like fiddler.  This tool acts as a proxy and is able to show http and https details.

Comment: @VíctorOriol   The python script is develop by multiple user, so can not force them to add loggers in each file. And setup separate apache web server is also overhead.So is there any unix package that we can track and store all the http/https request in file